# Github warns security problem about Omniauth gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github

I am using gem `omniauth` and when I push my code to Github, it shows me a security warning because of the gem.

```
CVE-2015-9284 
high severity
Vulnerable versions: <= 1.9.0
Patched version: No fix
The request phase of the OmniAuth Ruby gem is vulnerable to Cross-Site Request Forgery when used as part of the Ruby on Rails framework, allowing accounts to be connected without user intent, user interaction, or feedback to the user. This permits a secondary account to be able to sign into the web application as the primary account.
```

[image]

However, it seems that I am using the [latest version](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/releases)
[image]

Is there any possible fix, or should I skip this for now?

Comment: Please do not include screenshots of plaintext. Copy and paste the text into your post to make your post searchable and visible to users that may not be able to load the images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was reported in [omniauth/omniauth issue 960](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/issues/960) and discussed in [PR 809 "Protect request phase against CSRF when Rails is used. "](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/pull/809)

[It includes](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/pull/809#issuecomment-502079405):

> So we have implemented the **[`omniauth-rails_csrf_protection` solution](https://github.com/cookpad/omniauth-rails_csrf_protection)**, but previously we had our 3rd party OAuth provider log people in after they had verified the registration and redirect them to our `/auth/provider` endpoint.
>   This would now require them **POSTing to the endpoint with a CSRF token**, which is not possible as they are on a separate platform/system.
>
> Should the omniauth readme be updated to mention that anyone using omniauth with rails should also use `omniauth-rails_csrf_protection`?

See [commit 0264706](https://github.com/pulibrary/figgy/commit/0264706469cdc83e9911736bc2ad6eea4f112a20) as an example of using that setting.

```
gem "omniauth-rails_csrf_protection"
```

Or... [coreinfrastructure/best-practices-badge PR 1298](https://github.com/coreinfrastructure/best-practices-badge/pull/1298#issuecomment-504481701)

> I hate to bring in a third-party shim to fix a security issue, but upstream omniauth has *still* not fixed its vulnerability, and it's a CVE report from 4 years ago (2015).
>
> The omniauth folks are still discussing how to fix it, and my patience has been exhausted.
>
> I reviewed the shim code, and I don't see any issues. This is a vulnerability that allows account takeover, so I think ignoring it is extremely unwise. It's not trivial to exploit, but it's real.

Comment: I install the gem "omniauth-rails_csrf_protection" and push the code to repository but the issue is still there.
My Repository is: https://github.com/mhamzajutt96/sportscenter/network/alerts

Comment: @MuhammadHamza Strange. Maybe you ca report it in one of the issues I mention at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: But the issue is already opened, What the difference if I open it again

Comment: @MuhammadHamza Not to open it again, but to *add*, as a comment, a testimony of your issue (with details, Version, OS, ...) in order to signal the issue is not yet resolved.